# Is it correct to use multiple tenses within a paragraph in a story?

Tags: grammar, tense

I was wondering what tense I should use for writing a story. What I use is a Present and past tense mixture. But I am not sure whether they are right or wrong. If I write something general, I use present tense.

> The temple is situated on the river bank.

But if I describe some action, or a situation when the action occurs, I use past tense.

> The temple **is situated** on the river bank. In the evening many people **gather** in the temple.The river **runs** dry most of the year. By the time I **reached** the river bank the sun **had** already set. I **came** far, and the journey **was** very troublesome. There **are** cut marks all over my face, and hands.

*(Note that this is NOT a proofreading request.)*

I am not sure how to determine the tense. Is there a general rule to follow in situations like this? I would prefer an answer that's applicable beyond just this specific short paragraph.

Comment: As far as mixing tenses in the manner of your example, you need to split it into multiple paragraphs. Otherwise the reader simply gets confused trying to determine when things happen (or have happened? Or will? Or sort of did? We don't know.) But that gets into questions of writing style rather than language.

Comment: Related questions on Writers.SE: http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/8696/1993, http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/4428/1993, http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/6895/1993.  (Hat tip to Neil Fein for finding these.)

Comment: I would only use the present tense for describing the temple etc. if you want to emphasise that the events of the story happened recently in a real place which is still as you describe it. Normally, the past tense is used for setting the scene.

Answer (score 7):

I think where you run into trouble is in the last two sentences of the paragraph.

> I came far, and the journey was very troublesome. There are cut marks all over my face, and hands.

From the previous sentence (“By the time I reached the river bank. . .”) the reader is pointed to a specific moment in time. These last two sentences are then phrased in the simple past and present continuous, respectively. If I am correct that these last two sentences refer to the time you reached the river bank, they would be clearer as:

> I **had come** far, and the journey **had been** very troublesome. There **were** cut marks. . .

As far as a general rule, there aren’t strict prohibitions on combining any number of tenses in a single paragraph. My advice would be to study [past perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html), and diagram your paragraph temporally, like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's a story, then it must have occurred in the past.  Accordingly I recommend that you use the simple past, past continuous, past perfect, and past perfect continuous tenses exclusively.  I see no point in using any present tense.